# How to pass parameter to a local html file from java

Tags: javascript, java, html, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a java client which receive from the server longitude and latitude and  i need to send these coordinates as a parameter to an html file which is google map to locate these coordinates i need a way to open html file with passing parameters.
Thanks :)
here's the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

  <h1>My First Google Map</h1>

  <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

  <script>
    function myMap() {
      var mapProp = {
       center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850), //coordinates
       zoom:5,
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You will have to use JSP to pass Java variables to HTML or as an alternative you can also create a REST API to fetch the coordinates with ajax call on page load.

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: If both are new to you go check out some tutorials on google.

Comment: I've checked some tutorials about jsp and ajax ,, but i still confused about what method to use to let every client user pass his parameter does "GET" method works with this?

Comment: Yes GET method will work

Comment: So i guess it just need a web server not necessarily to use JSP

Comment: Ok it's done i've figured out ... i used get method with it and every thing is going alright